# ElasticSearch get offsets of highlighted snippets

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to get character positions of each highlighted fragment? I need to match the highlighted text back to the source document and having character positions would make it possible.

For example:

```
curl "localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "foo"
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "message": {"number_of_fragments": 20}
        }
    }    
}'
```

returns this highglight:

```
"highlight" : {
    "message" : [ "some <em>foo</em> text" ]
 }
```

If the field message in the matched document were:

```
"Here is some foo text"
```

is there a way to know that the snippet begins at char 8 and ends at char 21 of the matched field?

Knowing the start/end offset of the matched **token** would be good for me as well - perhaps there is a way to access that information using script_fields? (This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178550/elasticsearch-return-the-tokens-of-a-field) shows how to obtain the tokens, but not the offsets).

The field "message" has:

```
"term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",
"index_options" : "positions"
```

Comment: One way would be to set pre_tag to some character combination (i.e. ~!) and find it programatically on client side. Won't it work?

Comment: I could match on the default <em>, but I don't see how that would help me matching it back to the string in the field and retrieve the offsets. 
I'm OK, in principle, to solve this on the client side if there's a good solution.

Comment: Ok, It looks like I can use "number_of_fragments": 0 to get the full text of the field in the highlight. This gives me enough context to determine the offsets on client side. Still interested in better solutions :) This helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512656/elasticsearch-lucene-highlight

Comment: @raffazizzi Did you ever find a better solution?

Comment: No, sorry! This solution ended working well (even though admittedly it's not ideal).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The client-side approach is actually standard practice.

We have discussed adding the offsets, but are afraid it would lead to more confusion.  The offsets provided are specific to Java's UTF-16 String encoding, which, while they could technically be used to calculate the fragments from $LANG, it's way more straightforward to parse the response text for the delimiters you specified.

Comment: There's a feature request about it here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5736

Comment: So if I have a 10,000-page document and my user wants to search for an obscure term that's somewhere between pages 5000 and 6000, you expect me to download the entire document, and perform my own regex, in order to tell my user what page the term is on, even though you already have this information internally and are actually using it to make highlights efficiently. (And also this was 8 years ago!) Ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

We have ended up extending the original text like this:

> some[1] text[2] we[3] index[4]

Then we define a custom analyzer with:

```
"char_filter": {
        "remove_tags": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\\[[0-9]+\\]",
          "replacement": ""
```

Now in the highlighted snippets we get the location tags and we know where in the text they appear. Ugly, but works!

I gave a fuller answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820827/elasticsearch-location-of-fragments-in-a-document)