# Elasticsearch - location of fragments in a document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am executing a phrase query like the one below. It returns me the highlighted  fragments ordered by relevance. Naturally, I want the user to click on a fragment and I'd scroll the document to the corresponding location. However, I don't see any way in Elasticsearch to find out where the fragments are in the original document. Any ideas?

```
GET documents/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "text": {
                "query": "hello world",
                "slop":  10
            }
        }
    }, 
    "highlight" : {
        "order" : "score",
        "fields" : {
            "text" : {"fragment_size" : 100, "number_of_fragments" : 10}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Found any solution so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meantime we couldn't find a proper solution and ended up with the following hack (works very well for us):
Before indexing we annotate each word in the text with "[index]", so that "*some text to index*" becomes "*some[00] text[01] to[02] index[03]*". Then we use the char filter as shown below. When the highlights are returned we parse out the word positions from the highlight text.

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "remove_annotation": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\\[[0-9]+\\]",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "annotated_english_language_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "remove_annotation"
          ],
          ...
```

Note, the annotation indexes should be padded to `log10(text_length)+1` digits, so that the width of the found highlights (after annotations removal) would not depend on where (beginning vs. end of the text) it was found.

Comment: If the replacement is the empty string, doesn't that still mess with the highlighting?  I was thinking what you would do is pad the annotations so that you could replace them with a string of the same length (e.g. four spaces in your two-digit example above).  Otherwise, why bother padding the digits?

Comment: @JustinL. The purpose of replacing to "" in the filter is to allow normal searching, as we don't want our annotations to be stored in the reverse index. In our specific case we don't care about precise highlight width (as long as it is consistent along the text file) so we request quite wide highlight and after replacement of annotations get a shorter one to be presented to users.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was just confused why you were padding out the annotations to log10(text_length)+1 digits.  Originally, I thought it was so that the offsets of the tokens wouldn't change after the char_filter was applied, but now I'm not sure why you are bothering with the padding.

Comment: @JustinL. When you search with highlights you send into ES the required width of the highlight snippet in characters. If you don't pad the annotations you will end up with output highlights from the beginning of the document being longer than those found at the end of the document (because the annotations at the end are longer).